# R and RStudio don't display greek letters and other symbols - display squares instead

Tags: r, rstudio

I can't seem to display greek letters in r. I'm working with RStudio, and I can't seem to display greek characters no matter what I try. Initially I tried to display greek letters inside `bquote`, using syntax from a class I took, which the prof. published and demonstrated it worked in class. When all it showed was squares**, I tried more basic ways of displaying greek letters. I tried to use `expression` and than I tried to find the simplest way and ran this syntax which I found online:

```
mycoef <- rnorm (1000)
hist(mycoef, main = expression(beta))
```

In all cases it either display a square (like an unrecognized symbol), or just the word (beta, chi, etc.,). This syntax also displayed a square using R instead of RStudio.
I tried to change a bit the encoding of the file (ASCII/UTF-8), but this didn't change anything. I am working on a mac (macOS Sierra 10.12.4) if that changes anything.

**when using the `bquote` syntax, greek letters were not the only characters it changed to squares. Also == and ~~ without quotes were displayed as squares.

This is my `sessionInfo()` -
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] pt_PT.ISO8859-1/pt_PT.ISO8859-1/pt_PT.ISO8859-1/C/pt_PT.ISO8859-1/C

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.8.4      meta_4.8-4      openxlsx_4.0.17

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2    Rcpp_0.12.13

=====
Note that as a try to fix this problem I ran this syntax that is displayed in the sessionInfo - `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "pt_PT.ISO8859-1")`, which didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: Works as intended on my machine. Please provide your `sessionInfo()`. Does this display properly for you? β

Comment: I added the `sessionInfo()` in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't answer my question, does this (between the arrows) display properly? `-->` β `<--`

Comment: sorry, yes, when copying it into simple paste it display ok

Answer (score 0):

You can try using package `latex2exp` if you know the basics of LaTeX:

```
library(latex2exp)

mycoef <- rnorm (1000)
hist(mycoef, main = TeX("$\\beta$"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't resolved the problem. But thanks.

Comment: In RStudio, make sure Tools --> Global Options --> Code --> Saving --> "Default text encoding" is set to UTF-8.

Comment: In MacOS: Open Terminal --> Preferences --> Advanced --> Text encoding --> Unicode (UTF-8).

Comment: The preferences in Terminal were already set to UTF-8. I changed the settings following your recommendation in RStudio, but unfortunately this hasn't change anything. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem updating the Symbols Font on Windows. (1) Download the file Symbol.ttf (https://www.fontsupply.com/fonts/S/Symbol.html),
(2) Find the file symbol.ttf in your \Windows\Fonts folder, and replace with the fresh copy.