# Encoding greek characters in Rstudio

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

Similar to [R Wrong encoding in Rstudio console (but ok in R GUI and ggplot2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19900668/8689932)

I have the same problem with greek characters

I am running under Windows 10 and the version of Rstudio is 1.0.143

In RStudio, Tools --> Global Options --> Code --> Saving --> "Default text encoding" is set to UTF-8

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46756126/8689932), [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42702453/8689932) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20916070/8689932) didn;t help

Also, [The RStudio support on encoding](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding) didn;t help. Maybe something I am missing

I used

```
 Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Greek")
```

but that only solves the plotting and viewing of the df

---

Lets do an Example

```
#Create a dataframe

x<-c("Κόκκινο", "Κίτρινο","Πράσινο")
y<-c(5,4,9)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
names(df)<-c("colour","frequency")
```

When summarising with dplyr

```
> df%>%count(colour)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   colour     n
   <fctr> <int>
1 Êßôñéíï     1
2 Êüêêéíï     1
3 ÐñÜóéíï     1
```

When viewing the dataframe its all fine

```
 >View(df)
```

ggplot encodes just fine

```
ggplot(df,aes(colour,frequency))+geom_point()
```

Is there a way we can solve this?

My session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253    
LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2    janitor_0.3.0   scales_0.5.0    readxl_1.0.0    
dplyr_0.7.3     purrr_0.2.3     readr_1.1.1    
[8] tidyr_0.7.1     tibble_1.3.4    ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.1.1
```

Comment: does `print(x)` work correctly?

Comment: @Ista No it doesn't