# ggplot & latex2exp don't show correct symbols

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex2exp

I've tried using $\partial$ in a ggplot title but unfortunately it did not render correctly. In fact, when I try this example (https://uliniemann.com/blog/2022-02-21-math-annotations-in-ggplot2-with-latex2exp/), a lot of symbols are wrong. What could be the reason for this?

## Edit: It doesn't just affect ggpplot

```
plot(TeX(r'(A $\LaTeX$ test for $\partial$)'), cex=2, main="")
```

[image]

I also found the advise installing the font new ([R and RStudio don't display greek letters and other symbols - display squares instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756126/r-and-rstudio-dont-display-greek-letters-and-other-symbols-display-squares-in)) but this didn't work. Also see here: https://github.com/stefano-meschiari/latex2exp/issues/61

## Old post

```
# Copied example from link
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- tibble(x = rep(1:3, times = 3), y = rep(1:3, each = 3)) %>%
  mutate(z = c(
    r"($\alpha \beta \gamma$)", 
    r"($\Alpha \Beta \Gamma$)", 
    r"($\chi \psi \omega$)",
    r"($x^n + y^n = z^n$)",
    r"($\int_0^1 x^2 + y^2 \ dx$)",
    r"($\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \, \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}$)",
    r"($\left[ \frac{N} { \left( \frac{L}{p} \right) - (m+n) } \right]$)",
    r"($S = \{z \in \bf{C}\, |\, |z|<1 \} \, \textrm{and} \, S_2=\partial{S}$)",
    r"($\frac{1+\frac{a}{b}}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{a}}}$)"
  ))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = x, y = y, 
      label = TeX(z, output = "character")
    ), 
    parse = TRUE,
    size = 12/.pt
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.25, 0)) +
  scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0.25, 0))
```

**Expected outcome:**
[image]

**My outcome:**
[image]

**My info:**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.1.3     latex2exp_0.9.6 cowplot_1.1.1   ggplot2_3.5.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.11        pillar_1.9.0       compiler_4.2.2     RColorBrewer_1.1-3
 [5] R.methodsS3_1.8.2  viridis_0.6.4      R.utils_2.12.2     base64enc_0.1-3   
 [9] bitops_1.0-7       tools_4.2.2        ciftiTools_0.12.2  digest_0.6.33     
[13] evaluate_0.22      lifecycle_1.0.3    tibble_3.2.1       gtable_0.3.4      
[17] viridisLite_0.4.2  pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_1.1.1        RNifti_1.5.0      
[21] cli_3.6.1          oro.nifti_0.11.4   rstudioapi_0.15.0  gifti_0.8.0       
[25] yaml_2.3.7         xfun_0.40          fastmap_1.1.1      gridExtra_2.3     
[29] stringr_1.5.0      withr_2.5.1        knitr_1.44         xml2_1.3.5        
[33] generics_0.1.3     vctrs_0.6.4        grid_4.2.2         tidyselect_1.2.0  
[37] glue_1.6.2         R6_2.5.1           fansi_1.0.5        rmarkdown_2.25    
[41] sessioninfo_1.2.2  farver_2.1.1       magrittr_2.0.3     htmltools_0.5.6.1 
[45] splines_4.2.2      scales_1.3.0       abind_1.4-5        colorspace_2.1-0  
[49] labeling_0.4.3     utf8_1.2.3         stringi_1.7.12     munsell_0.5.0     
[53] R.oo_1.25.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug seem to be related to the R-version 4.2.2, because it does work for 4.3.3.